# Domino AppDev Pack 1.0.13, failed to startup iam services

Tags: node.js, domino-appdev-pack

Failed to startup domino-iam-services.  According to the tutorial https://doc.cwpcollaboration.com/appdevpack/docs/en/iam_setup_prepare_part.html

I have installed the database adpconfig.nsf for HCL Domino AppDev Pack Configuration.
At the access control page, I have granted the read access to IAMAccessors as tutorial.
I have created the self-signed SSL certificates, but failed to startup the demo services, IAM.

`enter code here` C:\iam>npm start

```
> domino-iam-service@2.2.0 start
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node iam-server.js
WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'production' did not match any deployment config file names.
WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
[17:40:58][info][master][master]: IAM version: 2.2.0
[17:40:58][warn][master][master]: IAM is in pilot mode. Please do not use this in production environment.
[17:40:58][warn][master][master]: To swith to production mode, delete config/local.properties then setup in production mode.
Start to unlock config:
? Enter current IAM server password: ************
Config is unlocked.
[17:41:09][info][master][master]: Starts as single node mode.
[17:41:09][info][initServices][master]: Start IAM service on allAddress:443
[17:41:09][info][stats][master]: IAM StatsClient enabled: false
[17:41:09][error][DBConnector][master]: Failed to obtain certificate content with: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
[17:41:09][error][adpConfig][master]: Error polling adpconfig. Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
at Object.readSync (node:fs:727:3)
at tryReadSync (node:fs:433:20)
at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:479:19)
at t (C:\iam\iam-server.js:1:57672)
at Object.g [as createCredentialOption] (C:\iam\iam-server.js:1:57795)
at Object.init (C:\iam\iam-server.js:1:9475)
at Object.init (C:\iam\iam-server.js:1:18954)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async e.exports (C:\iam\iam-server.js:1:87837)
at async C:\iam\iam-server.js:1:83053 {
errno: -4068,
syscall: 'read',
code: 'EISDIR'
}
[17:41:09][warn][IAMService][master]: LDAP has not been configured yet! Please go to Admin Service to configure it.`enter code here`
[17:41:09][error][initServices][master]: Exiting.. Error: keystore must be a JSON Web Key Set formatted object
[17:41:09][info][initServices][master]: IAM service is shutdown

C:\iam>
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIpue.png
```

Answer (score 0):

ADP config integration will likely not work in pilot mode. In pilot mode there is no set up connection to the domino server. You will need to configure it for production for that to work.

Comment: Could you elaborate more. What is pilot mode ? How to do the configuration ?

Comment: Pilot mode is where the IAM server starts up with a local mongo database to let people poke around with the software without needing a domino infrastructure to connect to.

Comment: The real configuration is detailed in the documentation that came with the appdev pack.  It involves creating a Domino ID for the application, creating an SSL certificate for it to connect to the proton server securely, and setting up the IAM server to use that certificate and the id's notes pw

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to use pilot mode setup, but failed.

Comment: >npm start
> domino-iam-service@2.2.0 start
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node iam-server.js

WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'production' did not match any deployment config file names.
WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
[12:45:02][info][master][master]: IAM version: 2.2.0
[12:45:02][warn][master][master]: IAM is in pilot mode. Please do not use this in production ...

Comment: [12:45:14][info][master][master]: Starts as single node mode.
[12:45:14][info][initServices][master]: Start IAM service on allAddress:443
......
    at Object.init (C:\domino-iam-service\iam-server.js:1:9475)
    at Object.init (C:\domino-iam-service\iam-server.js:1:18954)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async e.exports (C:\domino-iam-service\iam-server.js:1:87837)
    at async C:\domino-iam-service\iam-server.js:1:83053 {
  errno: -4068,
  syscall: 'read',
  code: 'EISDIR'

Comment: it looks like it's trying to do something on the filesystem and is getting an error with something that it's a directory instead of a file.

Comment: Can you open a support case so we can work more closely with you to resolve this issue?